# ArrayAdapter not executing the getView() method sometimes (depending on device)

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I have the following code for a sub class of ArrayAdapter left:

```
public class DashboardListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;
    Integer deviceID;
    private Integer size;

    public DashboardListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<RowItem> items, Bitmap b, Integer id) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.size = items.size();
        this.deviceID = id;
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        if (!isTablet(context))
        {
            holder.txtTitle.setTextSize(15);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return size;
    }
}
```

Which is being set into a ListView as so:

```
itemAdapter = new DashboardListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.menufragment_item, itemArray, bitmap, deviceID);
            lv.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
```

This runs when the app opens and works fine, but when i sync with the web services, I call a different method which passes in a a new set of List items, the ListView displays as empty and on debug the getView() within the adapter is never being called.

I have researched things and added the Overridden "getCount" method which worked at the time, now it does not work and shows the blank screen again. I have also changed the adapter to extend baseAdapter instead, and modifying the adapter class accordingly yet this problem persists.  To make matters more interesting, i have had no problems on the 10" Nexus tablet and the Nexus 4, while the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 and Nexus 7 (2012) seam to have this error occasionally.

When the ListView is blank and i rotate the screen, the display is refreshed and displays the correct information, same if i lock then unlock the device.

Comment: Please provide the code where your update your adapter with new data from service. Do you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after that ?

Comment: After getting the data from the web services and after calling `lv.setAdapter(itemAdapter)` do you call `itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I do not call `itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but without this and just calling `setAdapter()` was working for my primary testing devices (Nexus 10 and 4). I have just added it and it seams to work and not wipe the view... But then again tried it with the old code too and there were no issues.

Answer (score 1):

"When the ListView is blank and i rotate the screen, the display is refreshed and displays the correct information, same if i lock then unlock the device."

The only problem that can cause the getView() method not been called is the getCount returning 0 or something else then expected value.

As I see the only way you pass the item list is in the adapter constructor. This why it gets refreshed after screen rotation. (the activity is recreated so is your adapter, and voila!)

Your adapter should look like this:

```
   List<RowItem> items;

   public void setItemList(List<RowItem> newItems){
        this.items = newItems;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   public int getCount(){
        return this.items == null?0:this.items.size();

   }
```

When syncing you just call the setItemList(newSyncedItems);